# Google Trends keeps coming up in Chinese

Tags: google, google-chrome, firefox, localization, google-trends

I'm having a problem with Google trends: it keeps coming up in what it looks like Chinese.

I tried to eliminate several potential causes:

1. Signed out of my Google account -> still in Chinese.
2. Signed in with a different account -> still in Chinese.
3. Deleted all of the cookies -> still in Chinese.
4. Checked that my IP is not geolocated in China -> it's geolocated in the US.

I'm using Firefox 19.0.2, but when I try with Chrome it works just fine and Google Trends shows up in English. Any ideas what might be happening and/or how to fix it?

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try clicking this link, it may fix your problem:

http://www.google.com/trends/?hl=en

What happens is this: Google saves a state of your "current language" in their servers. They probably use this to customize ads for you.
This `"?hl=en"` parameter tells Google you prefer a different language (English in this example). It works across all their services.

Answer (score 2):

in 2019,using the "http://www.google.com/trends/?hl=en" can direct to english language on google trends,but when you type some words to search it return chinese again.

so there is another solution:

1. visit google account settings:https://myaccount.google.com
2. click Data & personalization-General preferences for the web-language,choose english and save
3. refresh google trends and search,then it works in english